# Combo Box Inserta campo Erróneo

Tags: vba, ms-access

les presento el siguiente error, tengo un formulario en Access en este tengo campos de tipo texto y dos Combo Box uno par Departamento y otro para Ciudades, al hacer el insert se agrega a la base de datos los ID de correspondientes es decir, el Id del Departamento y el Id de la ciudad que he elegido. Lo que necesito es que se agreguen los nombre.

Este es el código VBA.

```
Dim Sql As String
Sql = "INSERT INTO Entidades(Nombre,Direccion,Nit,Telefono,Correo,RUC,RubroEconomico,Departamento,Ciudad)" _
        & " VALUES('" & Me.txt_Nombre & "','" & Me.txt_Direccion & "','" & Me.txt_Nit & "','" & Me.txt_Telefono & "','" & Me.txt_Correo & "','" & Me.txt_RUC & "','" & Me.txt_Sector & "','" & Me.cbx_departamentos & "','" & Me.cbx_municipios & "')"
        
DoCmd.RunSQL Sql

End Sub



Private Sub Form_Load()
With Me.cbx_departamentos
.ColumnCount = 2
.ColumnWidths = 0
.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM departamentos ORDER BY departamento ASC"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub cbx_departamentos_AfterUpdate()
With Me.cbx_municipios
.ColumnCount = 2
.ColumnWidths = 0
.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE departamento_id Like '*" & Me.cbx_departamentos & "*' ORDER BY municipio ASC"

End With
Me.cbx_municipios = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Probaría cambiando el asterisco por el departamento:

```
.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM departamentos ORDER BY departamento ASC"
```

así:

```
.RowSource = "SELECT departamento FROM departamentos ORDER BY departamento ASC"
```

Lo mismo para municipio:

```
.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE departamento_id Like '*" & Me.cbx_departamentos & "*' ORDER BY municipio ASC"
```

así:

```
.RowSource = "SELECT municipio FROM municipios WHERE departamento_id Like '*" & Me.cbx_departamentos & "*' ORDER BY municipio ASC"
```

De ese modo seleccionará el campo departameno de la tabla departamentos. Si además te interesa el Id, añade una coma (,) y el Id:

.RowSource = "SELECT departamento, Id FROM departamentos ORDER BY departamento ASC"
(en el supuesto que la clave primaria está definida con el nombre 'Id')

Por cierto, cuando añadas el combobox al formulario, asegúrate de que cancelas el asistente (Wizard) que aparece.

Comment: Xavier Junqué, el SELECT funciona bien pues muestra los registro en este caso todos los nombres, pero es al momento de hacer el INSERT que agrega los ID y no los nombres.

Comment: Es en el INSERT donde tienes que hace un JOIN de tu tabla departamentos y municipios para traerte la denominación en lugar del ID.